# Randomize something the same way on two classes

Tags: jquery, css, html, random, parent-child

I'm trying to achieve something of which I've got (the smaller) half done thanks to [this community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978657/randomly-added-classes-for-divs-with-same-class) :) — no clue how to do the rest, though.

I have multiple instances of a `div`. To each instance I randomly add a class from a list (to change some settings like font, colors etc). currently i am doing so with with the function below. this function additionally avoids two identical classes to be added right after one another.

```
var classes = ['blue', 'yellow', 'lightorange', 'violet'];
var prevClass = "";
$('.randomizeddiv').each(function() {
    var classes2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (classes[i] !== prevClass) {
            classes2.push(classes[i]);
        }
    }
    $(this).addClass(prevClass = classes2[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes2.length)]);
});
```

Now I have another `div` with a different class (also multiple instance) which I want to change in respect to how the previous was changed. lets say my first randomized `div` was added the class "blue" I want a child-div to turn "blue2"

```
    <div class="randomizeddiv blue> 
        </div class="secondrandom blue2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="randomizeddiv yellow> 
        </div class="secondrandom yellow2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="randomizeddiv violet> 
        </div class="secondrandom violet2"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the child in the loop ?

```
var classes = ['blue', 'yellow', 'lightorange', 'violet'];
var prevClass = "";

$('.randomizeddiv').each(function() {
    var classes2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (classes[i] !== prevClass) {
            classes2.push(classes[i]);
        }
    }

    prevClass = classes2[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes2.length)]

    $(this).addClass(prevClass).find('.secondrandom').addClass(prevClass + '2');
});
```